# Кубический метр форматировать в тег <sup>3</sup>

Tags: javascript, html

Как с помощью js можно выделить уже на фронте готовый html код

дано

```
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ м3</div>
```

хочется все эти единицы измерения, где есть кубический метр выделить в тег 
так

```
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ м<sup>3</sup></div>
```

Comment: На сервере менять надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По мотивам [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513762/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3-sup3-sup#comment2717277_1513762) участника [Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy):

> Запросите все дивы с классом "price", сделайте замену м3 -> м<sup>3</sup> в innerHtml.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.price').forEach(el => el.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace(/м(2|3)/i, 'м<sup>$1</sup>'));
```

```html
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ м3</div>
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ М3</div>
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ м<sup>3</sup></div>
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ м<sup>2</sup></div>
```

Вариант с сохранением существующей разметки и регистра букв:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.price').forEach(el => el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(м)(2|3)/i, '$1<sup>$2</sup>'));
```

```html
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ м3</div>
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ М3</div>
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ м<sup>3</sup></div>
<div class="price">от 400 <b>₽</b> м<sup>3</sup></div>
<div class="price">от <i>400 ₽ M<sup>2</sup></i></div>
```

Comment: Нельзя читать textContent и писать в innerHTML.

Comment: @Qwertiy: это почему нельзя? Просто немного другой подход. Здесь это сделано намеренно на случай, если замена будет производиться повторно, и попадёт уже изменённый элемент. То есть, чтобы не было ситуации `<sup><sup>3</sup></sup>`. Основную задачу код выполняет, ни о каких вложенных тегах в вопросе речи не было.

Comment: Потому что XSS.

Comment: @Qwertiy: пожалуйста, внимательно прочитайте заголовок вопроса. _"Non sunt entia multiplicanda praeter necessitatem"_.

Comment: Отсылки к вопросу - не оправдание. ТС мало знает про предмет. В паре `textContent` -> `innerHTML` есть вектор для атаки и неожиданное поведение для некоторых данных. Если можно избавится от обоих недостатков без снижения основной функциональности - имеет смысл это сделать. Это не "умножение сущностей".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy: тогда читайте комментарий под вопросом - это надо автору вопроса донести, а не костыли мастерить.

Answer (score 3):

Запросите все дивы с классом "price", сделайте замену `м3` -> `м<sup>3</sup>` в `innerHTML`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.price').forEach(
    el => el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(
        /(м)3/gi, '$1<sup>3</sup>'
    )
);
```

```html
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ м3</div>
<div class="price">от 400 ₽ М3</div>
<div class="price">от <i>400 ₽ м3</i></div>
<div class="price">от <i>400 ₽ М3</i></div>
<div class="price">от <i>400 ₽ м3</i> до <i>500 ₽ м3</i></div>
```

Comment: В чём смысл скобочной группы в вашем ответе?

Comment: @UModeL, сохраняю регистр буквы `м` (`М`).

Comment: как вариант заменить регулярку на (?<=м)3, тогда м не будет заменяться

Comment: Ради интереса загнал вопрос ТС в ChatGPT без изменений, он предложил сделать так `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("price")).map(el => el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/м3/g, "м<sup>3</sup>"));` Интересно, как это отслеживается на stack ?

Comment: @Rudi, если ответ правильный то с авторством проблем быть не должно. Ответ с `Array` странный.

Comment: Как-то не честно это всё по моему.. Но GPT полезная штука.. Сегодня переводил один свой ответ с JS на Ruby, по началу говорил, что не умеет, но в итоге переписал, всё работает... И это V-3 бота в телеге нашел.. Скоро будем конкурировать за право дать ответ)) По крайней мере перевод с одного ЯП на другой на stack частенько минусят тут GPT на шаг впереди..

Comment: @Rudi, если вы про портирование без знания и алгоритма и обоих языков, то, что результат вроде работает на примерах, не означает ничего. Переполнения, обработка ошибок, специальные случаи в данных - это всё не учитывается. Получается вроде работающий код. Размер этого "вроде" не известен.

Comment: Согласен с вами. Думаю у V-5 будет получаться конкурировать с человеком, не во всем и не всегда будет получаться, но штука будет мощная. В целом многое зависит от формулировки запроса. GPT помнит контекст и может в нем ориентироваться. И конечно, на запрос "сделай мне адаптивный сайт" он не ответит готовым кодом)